# Why PDFPlumber not working with PysimpleGUI?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Currently, the python source file does not run into any compile errors but its not executing the backend process which converts the data from a pdf table to a csv file. Here is my source code:

```
sg.theme('Dark Blue 3')  # please make your creations colorful

layout = [  [sg.Text('Select a PDF FILE')],
            [sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("pdf file", "*.pdf"),))],
            [sg.Text('Save a CSV filename')],
            [sg.Input(), sg.FileSaveAs(file_types=(("csv file", "*.csv"),))], 
            [sg.OK(), sg.Cancel()]] 

window = sg.Window('PDF TO CSV FILE EXTRACTION', layout)

event, values = window.read()

if event == "OK" and len(values[0])!= 0 and len(values[1]) != 0:
    outfile = open(values[1], 'w')
    outcsv = csv.writer(outfile)

    with pdfplumber.open(values[0]) as pdf:
        first_page = pdf.pages[0]
        table = first_page.extract_table()
        for row in table[0:]:
            outcsv.writerow(row)
        outfile.close
    
    sg.popup('CONVERSION COMPLETED, Exit program')
    loop = True
    

elif event == "Cancel":

    sg.popup('OPERATION TERMINATED')
    break

elif len(values[0])== 0 or len(values[1]) == 0:

    sg.popup_error('INPUT IS MISSING, TERMINATING PROGRAM. CONTACT YOUR SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR.')
    loop = True    

else: 
    sg.popup_error('UNKNOWN INPUT, TERMINATING PROGRAM. CONTACT YOUR SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR.')
    break



window.close()
```

Comment: No import statement, SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Answer (score 1):

It do execute the backend process, and do everything.
The only problem was you didn't close the csv file.

Wrong statements

```py
outfile.close
```

Correct one

```py
outfile.close()
```